# Transforming a dataframe of probabilities for specific periods to be probabilities of at least once over n periods?

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I've got a dataframe which has probabilities for different events over a large number of sequential periods, and I want to transform this df to show the probability of something happening at least once over n periods. eg, I've got this, which would be n = 1:

```
event | period   | probability
A     | period 1 | 0.6
A     | period 2 | 0.7
A     | period 3 | 0.8
A     | period 4 | 0.85
A     | period 5 | 0.9
```

And I want to figure out the probability of A occurring at least once across two periods (n = 2), which would be:

```
A | period 1 | 1-(1-0.6)*(1-0.7)
A | period 2 | 1-(1-0.7)*(1-0.8)
A | period 3 | 1-(1-0.8)*(1-0.85)
A | period 4 | 1-(1-0.85)*(1-0.9)
```

And n = 3 would be:

```
A | period 1 | 1-(1-0.6)*(1-0.7)*(1-0.8)
A | period 2 | 1-(1-0.7)*(1-0.8)*(1-0.85)
A | period 3 | 1-(1-0.8)*(1-0.85)*(1-0.9)
```

Is there some python / pandas function or term that'd work here?

Comment: In the first case where `n=2` you would also have period 4, right?

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that: A | period 4 | 1-(1-0.85)*(1-0.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby with transform:

```
n = 2

df['new_probability'] = df.groupby('event')['probability'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(n).agg(lambda y: 1-np.prod(1-y)).shift(-n+1))

print(df)
event   period  probability  new_probability
A  period1         0.60            0.880
A  period2         0.70            0.940
A  period3         0.80            0.970
A  period4         0.85            0.985
A  period5         0.90              NaN
```

For `n=3`:

```
n = 3

df['new_probability'] = df.groupby('event')['probability'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(n).agg(lambda y: 1-np.prod(1-y)).shift(-n+1))

print(df)
event   period  probability  new_probability
A  period1         0.60            0.976
A  period2         0.70            0.991
A  period3         0.80            0.997
A  period4         0.85              NaN
A  period5         0.90              NaN
```

Comment: Looks perfect but I'm unsure how this works and I've given a simplified example. There are many events determined by combinations of multiple columns, eg. col 1 can be A/B/C and col 2 is X/Y/Z. Events would be AX, AY, AZ, BX, BY... Could this be applied in the same way?

Comment: Yes, it can! I tested creating another event B and it worked perfectly, it does not depends on the number of events, it is grouped by each one. @ChrisDixon

Comment: Bro you are an absolute legend. Thank you so much!